# Select multiple objects many to many

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

There are following models:

```
class Schema(models.Model):
    keys = models.ManyToManyField(Key, through='SchemaHasKey')
    # ...

class Key(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # ...
```

I need select 10 first schemas with the keys, but my way is bad:

```
schemas = []

for schema in Schema.objects.all().order_by('pk')[:10]:
    schema.key = schema.keys.all()
    schemas.append(schema)
```

.select_related() is not work well:

```
schemas = Schema.objects.select_related().order_by('pk')[:10]
```

This can be done in a certain number of sql queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I might do it until `prefetch_related` functionality is officially launched.

2 queries.

```
from collections import defaultdict

schemas = Schema.objects.order_by('pk')[:10]
key_map = defaultdict(lambda:[]) # always return a list

# use m2m through table to get all schema-key relationships related to the 10
# create a list of each `Key` with the Schema ID as the dict key.
[key_map[through.schema.id].append(through.key) for 
    through in Schema.keys.through.objects.filter(schema__in=schemas)]

for schema in schemas:
    schema.keys = key_map[schema.id]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be ".append(key_through.key)"? Also, don't you need to wrap "key_map[schema.id]" in a try in case a schema has no keys?

Comment: One more thing- With my setup (django 1.1), .through seems to only be set on objects pulled from the db, not on the manager. Nice improvement with defaultdict!

Comment: @Dan, are you sure? I feel like I've always accessed the through model from the manager. `Class.m2m.through` or `instance.m2m.through`. Perhaps it was added recently..

Comment: I checked and when I do "SomeClass.many_to_many_field.through" I get "AttributeError: 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'through'".

Comment: @Dan then it's as you say! It must have been added in >1.1 :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** `prefetch_related` only works in Django development version.

I think you can use djangos [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) functionality. It also supports ManyToMany fields. It doesn't do the join in one SQL query but it might speed it up different ways.

It can be used like this:

```
Schema.objects.all().prefetch_related('keys').order_by('pk')[:10]
```

Comment: @Deadly I see, nevermind then. They should consider writing it in a bigger font in their docs :).